# Movie Clip Not Pointing At Mouse Correctly //AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I use this code to make my movie clip point at where my mouse is, but it isn't turning correctly. It turns like it's shifted. Like the center of the movie clip is wrong? Anyone can help me?

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
   dx = _parent._xmouse-_x;
   dy = _parent._ymouse-_y;
   angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
   _rotation = angle * 180/Math.PI;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame){
   if(Key.isDown(68)){
      this._x += 1.5;
   }
   if(Key.isDown(65)){
      this._x -= 1.5;
   }
   if(Key.isDown(87)){
      this._y -= 1.5;
   }
   if(Key.isDown(83)){
      this._y += 1.5;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely related to the fact that the MovieClip you are working on has its pivot point somewhere else than in the center. Enter flash, inside your mc that is rotating, place it so that the center of mass is located at 0,0